Nuxt3: graphQLErrors in a composable
I'm using useAsyncQuery in a Nuxt3 App and want to access the graphQLErrors. It seems that important attributes like extensions and path are not part of the error object in a composable object.
const { data, error } = await useAsyncQuery<{ my_service: { blabla: BlablaGraph} }>(params);
-- only error.value.message provides something usefull

Basically, everything works, and I see that the desired information is returned from the Backendservice in the file plugins/apollo.ts. Here in the error Object everything (message, path, extensions...) is there.
const errorLink = onError(error => {
    nuxtApp.callHook('apollo:error', error); // must be called bc `@nuxtjs/apollo` will not do it anymore
});

So, how can I access the graphQLErrors in a composable?
Package versions:
"@nuxtjs/apollo": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
"graphql": "^16.6.0",
"nuxt": "3.5.0",


I solved this by writing the graphQLErrors into the message. Then there is everything you want in the composable. Dirty, but it works.
 const errorLink = onError(error => {
    error.graphQLErrors!.at(0)!.message = JSON.stringify(error.graphQLErrors);
    nuxtApp.callHook('apollo:error', error);
 });

